# Visualizing big-data xy regression plots in R (maybe contour histograms?)

Tags: r, contour

I have 1 million x-y data points.  100,000 of them are from foo; 900,000 of them are from bar.  And perhaps a few unusual mass points.  Let me help my audience visualize them, and not merely the regression or loess lines but the data.  Let me draw bars in red, and foos in blue, and then my two loess lines on top of them. think something like

```
K <- 1000 ; M <- K*K ; HT <- 100*K
x <- rnorm(M); y <- x+rnorm(M); y[1:HT] <- y[1:HT]+1 ; x[HT:(HT*2)] <- y[HT:(HT*2)] <- 0
pdf(file="try.pdf")
plot( x, y, col="blue", pch=".")
points( x[1:HT], y[1:HT], col="red", pch="." )
## scatter.smooth( x[1:HT], y[1:HT] ), but this seems to take forever
dev.off()
```

this is not only *not* a great visual (for example, the high-elevation zero point is lost), but also creates a 7.5MB(!) pdf file.  my previewer almost chokes on it, too.  (hint:  jpeg compression is pretty good for the problem.  that is, instead of the `pdf()`, just use `jpeg` and a different file extension.  drawback:  the axes become fuzzily compressed, too.)

so, I need some better ideas.  I am thinking two-dimensional filled.contourplot on the full data set (in a gray-scale reaching not too far towards black), with a plain contour overlay of the 1:HT points, and then two loess overlays.  alas, even to do this, I need to start off smoothing the number of data points that appear at an x-y location, and presumably binning-first is not the best way to do this---it would throw away information, which the contour plot could use.

alternatively, I could stay with the standard xy plot, and simply cull random points until the file is small enough and the visuals good enough.  this could be done perhaps better via binning, too.

better ideas?

Comment: Pkg:`hexbin` is very useful for 2D-displaying high count data. Although any sort of 2D display (including xyplots) usually requires that there be some sort of 1 to 1 correspondence. And that doesn't seem possible with what you describe.